# How do I find out the subdivisions N_1, N_2 and N_3 in BAND STRUCTURE?

Tags: vasp, k-points

I want to find out how to get subdivisions from vasprun.xml of Brillouin zone. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: +1 But did you figure out the answer to this over the last ~7 months?

Comment: @NikeDattani Well I did it, You can't do that in a band structure calculation mode. Because this particular calculation mode takes points along a certain path. That is, the electronic structure is not calculated for the entire Brillouin zone, the usual DOS calculation is suitable for calculating the entire zone

Comment: it sounds like you have an answer to this question now?